# Extract Inline attachments using java mail api?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, imap

I am able retrieve the regular attachments with the following code. 
But not the inline attachments like images pasted in email body. 
My goal is to download the regular attachments and inline attachments(pasted in body)in local folder.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.!!

```
public class GetEmails3 {
     public GetEmails3() {}
     private static void deleteEmails(String protocol, String host, final String userName, final String password, String provider)
     throws Exception {
         //Start
         Properties properties;
         Session session;
         properties = new Properties();
         properties.setProperty("mail.host", "192.168.2.40");
         //properties.setProperty("mail.port", "995");
         properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imap");
         session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
             protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                 return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
             }
         });
         try {
             Store store = session.getStore("imap");
             store.connect();
             Folder inboxFolder = store.getFolder("Inbox");
             inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
             System.out.println("Connected successfully ");
             Message[] messages = inboxFolder.getMessages();
             int messageCount = messages.length;
             System.out.println("Total Messages:- " + messageCount);
             for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                 Message message = messages[i];
                 String messageContent = "";
                 String attachFiles = "";
                 String contentType = message.getContentType();
                 if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                     Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
                     int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                     for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                         MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                         String disposition = part.getDisposition();
                         String file = part.getFileName();
                         //External attachments
                         if (disposition != null && Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                             String fileName = new Date().getTime() + "_" + part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_"); //To make attachment name uniq we are adding current datatime before name.
                             attachFiles += fileName + ","; //concrete all attachment's name with comma separated.                  
                             part.saveFile("TestAttachments/" + fileName);
                         } //Inline Attachments
                         else if (disposition != null && Part.INLINE.equalsIgnoreCase(disposition)) {
                             // this part is attachment
                             String fileName = new Date().getTime() + "_" + part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_"); //To make attachment name uniq we are adding current datatime before nam                
                             part.saveFile("TestAttachments/" + fileName); //To save the attachment file at specific location.
                         } //Inline icons and smileys
                         else if (file != null && disposition == null) {
                             String fileName = new Date().getTime() + "_" + part.getFileName().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\._]+", "_");
                             //  attachFiles += fileName + ","; //concrete all attachment's name with comma separated.
                             part.saveFile("TestAttachments/" + fileName);
                         }
                     }
                 }
             } //message for end
         } catch (MessagingException e) {
             System.out.println("Error when creating the email store ");
             throw new Exception("Error when creating the email store ", e);
         }
         //End
     }
 }
```

Comment: If it's inline, it's not really an attachment, is it?  :-)  But the question is, what exactly do you mean by an inline attachment?  Can you show us the MIME source of a message with such an attachment?  Is this an image whose base64 encoded bits are included directly in the html of a page?  If so, you'll have to parse the html to find the "attachment".

Comment: @Bill looping trhough part 0multipart/alternative; 
 boundary="=_b9b4a9b36dfbb1d47a15183ae9367c13"
looping trhough part 1multipart/alternative; 
 boundary="=_b9b4a9b36dfbb1d47a15183ae9367c13"

Comment: I don't understand.  Was that supposed to be an answer to my questions?  If you're dealing with multipart/alternative messages, you have to understand that none of the parts in that multipart are "attachments".